# large size images or video uploading to cloud should handle client side or server side

Tags: angularjs, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

We want to upload large images or videos on cloud. But which will be a better option between Client Side (Angular Js) and Server Side(ASP.Net Web API). Both having some pros and cons. But i don't know which will be better. If anyone can suggest with reasons then that will be a great help me.